# Why Chrome DevTools Screenshot get the full rendered web page at the very beginning (1ms)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, html-rendering

Chrome DevTools Screenshot get the full rendered web page at the very beginning (about 1ms)，and then the page is blank and normal rendering process begins, I want to know why this happened.

[image: strange things]

**PS:It is obvious when the page is rendered by the client.**

Comment: Here you specify the Google-chrome-devtools, so I wonder if Firefox gives you a different frames?

Comment: Maybe cached data is used, hence the speed...